# How to check if a C# Bitmap is valid before adding it to a picturebox

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, picturebox

How can I check if a C# [System.Drawing.Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) image is valid before adding it to a picturebox?

Comment: What is the source of the image ? Are you loading it from a file / resource / stream ?

Comment: Could you please add more details, like where do you get Bitmap instance from? created from file?

Comment: Hi! I'm loading it from web! A jpeg image! But sometimes that is empty ^^.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "empty" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty simple.  If you can load the image before you assign it to the picture box then you've sufficiently proven that the image is valid and that the user has something to look at.  The GDI+ image decoders very carefully check the file contents.  Thus:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) != DialogResult.OK) return;
        try {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Could not load image");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Define "valid"
2. write a valdation function
3. call it on the image
4. if it passes, load the image, otherwise don't

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should check this 'RawFormat' property of the 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' class as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rawformat.aspx) on MSDN. If the image is empty, that will throw an exception and you can trap it in that case.